# Is there a MSDN Forum API?

Tags: api, forum, msdn

Want to know if there's an API through which the MSDN Forums can be accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of January 2013, there is not yet an API for the MSDN Forums.  One thing you *can* do is append the string "?outputas=xml" to the URL of a Forums page and process the resulting XML (as in this [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualstudiogeneral/thread/4dcea7c5-160c-495e-b7e6-bfc7e11e6ab4?outputas=xml)).  While not a replacement for an API, this approach enables some scenarios.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of using XML and RSS outputs. Just wanted to make sure that there's no MS API for this.